# Paypal adaptive payments and IPN

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-adaptive-payments

I am making use of Paypal adaptive payments using [AngellEye librar](http://www.angelleye.com/demo/codeigniter/paypal/adaptive_payments/)y.

Everything works great except IPN. When using Paypal in Sandbox mode I get a notifications to my URL. However, as soon as I go live I get no IPN POST requests to my server. I checked my Apache access.log.

Do I need to enable Paypal IPN for live adaptive payments somewhere?

In my Paypal account, under selling preferences, it shows IPN as disabled. To enable it and I need to also supply a URL. However, my URL is dynamic and I assumed since I am using the Paypal API, I do not need to change this?

Usage of IPN:

```
    $PayRequestFields = array(
        'ActionType' => 'CREATE',                                               
        'CancelURL' => base_url() . 'd/cancel/' . $this->transactionID,                                    
        'CurrencyCode' => $this->product->currency, 
        'ReturnURL' => base_url() . 'd/success/' . $this->transactionID,
        'FeesPayer' => 'PRIMARYRECEIVER',
        'IPNNotificationURL' => base_url() . 'ipn/status/' . $this->transactionID,  
        );
```

Comment: Did you already enable Instant Payment Notifications in your Live PayPal Account? Let me know if you need instructions.

Comment: @pp_MSI_Jenn Are you referring to settings in my Paypal account? If so, I have not enabled it as it requires a URL which is dynamic for my application. Can it not be enabled programmatically?

Comment: I've updated my question to show how I use Andrew's library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted Paypal support and this is what they had to say:

> I checked your current IPN settings for your account and it appears
>   IPN is set to 'Off', not 'Disabled'. This is a very important
>   difference, as IPN being disabled prevents IPN messages from being
>   sent at all. If IPN is simply turned off, PayPal will only send IPN
>   messages if a notify_url is specified in the payment request. For
>   Adaptive Payments, the notify_URL is the only way to trigger IPN
>   messages, so IPN can be in the 'Off' setting and worked correctly, but
>   not disabled.

This was received after I randomly fixed the problem myself. The way I got it to work was simply playing around with my account settings. I enabled IPN in my account and then disabled it, after this all my IPN requests came flooding in to my IPN URL set in my Adaptive Payments API call.

Comment: I will select my answer as the correct one as it did fix my issue but no idea why. In addition, I will award Andrew for his continued help and for his awesome library which I have been using for over a year.

Comment: Ah, I should have remembered that.  Glad they helped you out, and I'm glad you like the library!

Answer (score 7):

Adaptive Payments IPN's are a little different in that the application will receive one (if configured) and then the merchant/seller account would also get one based on the actual transaction they received.

For example, if your app generates a Pay request on behalf of a 3rd party user and you set the NotificationURL in the Pay request, then an app specific IPN would be sent to that URL.  A transaction specific IPN would be sent to the URL that the seller account has configured in their own PayPal account.

You also need to make sure your IPN script is configured to handle the Adaptive IPN's correctly.  The parameter names that it sends are like some.name, and the . doesn't work with regular $_POST['paramname'] logic.  Check out this [IPN template](https://github.com/paypal/ipn-code-samples/blob/master/paypal_ipn.php) for how it handles it...you may just want to use it.

Here's a sample of an application IPN I received when I ran a Pay request just now.

```
Array
(
    [transaction] => 
    [payment_request_date] => Tue May 06 12:49:35 PDT 2014
    [return_url] => http://paypal.angelleye.com/paypal/class/1.2/Pay_Return.php
    [fees_payer] => EACHRECEIVER
    [ipn_notification_url] => http://sandbox.angelleye.com/paypal/ipn/ipn-listener.php
    [sender_email] => tester@angelleye.com
    [verify_sign] => AFcWxV21C7fd0v3bYYYRCpSSRl31ArVBOvsxhUiZ-m0M3mFjhNWWaRjM
    [test_ipn] => 1
    [cancel_url] => http://paypal.angelleye.com/paypal/class/1.2/Pay_Cancel.php
    [pay_key] => AP-8YH799874R4873815
    [action_type] => PAY
    [transaction_type] => Adaptive Payment PAY
    [status] => INCOMPLETE
    [log_default_shipping_address_in_transaction] => false
    [charset] => windows-1252
    [notify_version] => UNVERSIONED
    [reverse_all_parallel_payments_on_error] => false
)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. :-) I am processing payments for 3rd party users. I did a search in Apache access.logs and I do not get a request hitting my server at all for the IPN URL set via `IPNNotificationURL`. It would be just great to see a POST request to my server. Thank you for the template btw.

Comment: You sure you have it configured correctly?  I just tested the Pay request from my library and added the IPNNotificationURL.  I received the IPN as expected.  I've updated my answer with the IPN sample.

Comment: OK so, I just enabled IPN in my Paypal account with my homepage URL?! This seems to have done the trick and I am receiving POST requests! No where in the documentation does it say to do this?!

Comment: That shouldn't be necessary.  With that, when that account receives transactions it would POST data to your home page URL, but I'm assuming that URL doesn't actually have logic to handle IPN's, right?  That would be wasted resources and could even result in errors getting returned to PayPal's IPN server.  You may want to check your IPN History.

Comment: I had a look at my IPN history and I can see loads of past transactions with status disabled. And then others with `Sent` and `Retrying`. The ones that have been sent are to the correct URL and the retries is to the wrong URL (homepage). One is of type `Transaction made` and the other is `Adaptive payment made`. I have disabled IPN on my account again as I do not like those errors! When turning IPN off, the message was clear that I would not receive IPN messages.

Comment: When setting IPN in API calls, though, it overrides your profile setting, so you should still get them to the URL you set in the Pay request.

Comment: Thanks for the continued help Andrew, but I still do not receive IPN to my live server although I do with Sandbox using the same exact code. It seems like a Paypal Account issue. I have contacted Paypal support and lets see what they reply with. I will add bounty to this as well.

Comment: Yes, the IPN history shows disabled next to all IPN requests that could have been made.

Comment: My sever logs (access.log) show no requests for my IPN URL. My staging server does show these requests though but that is in Sandbox mode.

Comment: Are you sure you're getting what you expect out of base_url()?  According to the sample IPN you're showing here it actually used my test server's IPN URL on sandbox.angelleye.com.

Comment: Ye my base_url() is definitely correct. When I look at IPN history I can see it going to the correct URL. I noticed this when I enabled IPN in my account for a few minutes.

Comment: Well something is wrong there.  Your own sample is showing my sandbox.angelleye.com server as your IPN listener, and when I check that site, sure enough, I see an IPN with your PayKey on that same date and time.

Comment: What are you seeing that in your IPN history? Also when you say "your own sample" which are you referring to as the code I pasted in SO does not have `sandbox.angelleye.com`.

Comment: LOL, sorry, I was being an idiot and looking at my own post.  Scratch that last statement.  Still, though, it's working fine for me when I include the IPN URL in the API request.  Can you post a sample of your actual request instead of the code generating it?

Comment: Hehe, thanks for clearing that up I thought I was going mental! Btw, really appreciate your continued help and awesome library! Paypal have got back to me, see my answer.

Comment: At the moment, in the sandbox, I have an IPN Notification url specified in my test seller's profile as well as when my application sends a PAY request (in the IpnNotificationUrl field). This causes my listener to be hit twice for the same transaction (I cannot enable IPN Notification for the account without specifying a valid URL). Is this setup correct? 
As you mention, the IPN's are slightly different from one another. I definitely need the IPN generated by the app because it contains the `custom`field...Should I be receiving both IPN's or should I find a configuration when I only receive 1?